# Replace text in costomized TextView

Tags: android, textview, left-to-right

I am trying to replace the text in a customized text view. the purpose is to force the text to be LTR; In order to do that, I am adding the "\u200E" prefix to my text.
Right now the setText() does not take any affect on the customized textView.

```
public class LocalizedTextView extends TextView {
    public LocalizedTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public LocalizedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public LocalizedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        this.setText("\u200E" + getText().toString());
    }
}
```

And this is the customized element:

```
<com.tempProject.customviews.LocalizedTextView
    android:id="@+id/item_text"
    style="@style/DrawerSectionText"
    android:textDirection="ltr" />
```

Any Idea to force textView with RTL content to align to the left for devices older than 4.2.0, will be more than welcome.
The android:supportsRtl flag has to be set to true in the manifest.

Comment: try android:gravity="left"

Comment: It does not change the direction of the text...